# support for multiple entity id in spring-oauth

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented a spring oauth-server and using SFDC as idp, in sfdc i have created a app and given the entity id =com.xyz.abc also downloaded metadata and integrated with my code .
In my oauth server properties file i have given -
**idp.enity.id= com.xyz.abc**
for single Entity id it is working fine.
now i want to create another app in SFDC and want to give entity id =com.xyz.lmno.shas and in my properties file want to do like this-
idp.entity.id = com.xyz.lmno.shas
finally my property file should contain two entity id's so that i can get the response from my selected app . 
Is it possible to give two or more entity id's in property file